# Epson BX305FW Plus printing issues

Tags: printing

I have an Epson printer that seems to have an issue aligning magenta and yellow. I've gone through aligning the print heads multiple times. It prints fine from my ipad which makes me think it's a software issue on the pc side.

I've made sure im using the latest drivers for my os (8.1 64bit) and i've also made sure the printer is on the latest firmware.

[image: Photo of the problem]

I'm not sure what else to try!

Comment: Have you tried installing Windows drivers from Epson, e.g. http://esupport.epson-europe.com/ProductHome.aspx?lng=en-GB&data=FCFfEfoyEiHzptlkFs1T6qnE26OBh+K2kBy8NGbDoZgU003D&tc=6 ? You might need to uninstall current drivers first.

Comment: What the image shows doesn't look like an alignment problem (confirmed by normal printing from the iPad).  The colors cannot get that far off via alignment.  The problem isn't likely the printer, itself.  Print from several different applications to confirm that it isn't software.  Best bet is the driver.